# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have  developed on application for sending email. I have  Specified SMTP address, credentials, and I am using Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.

I am getting this error:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay
>   for Abc@xyz.com
>
> To fix it you have to configure relay restrictions in the IIS admin.

But where this option in IIS Server 7?

Answer (score 1):

To configure relay restrictions in IIS admin follow below mentioned steps

1. Go to “Default SMTP Virtual Server” in IIS and then go to properties
2. Select tab “Access”
3. Select last Option "Relay Restriction" by clicking the "Realy" button

a new window will pop up

4. Select the appropriate radio button and add IP addresses accordingly